# Do a frequency of word count on an RSS feed

Tags: java, rss

So I made a program that takes data from NPR's RSS feed and now I'm curious about how to do a frequency of word count on the descriptions within the feed here are my two programs which I'm trying to consolidate.

```
    package twp.brady.barry;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RSSReader {





    public static String readRSS(String urlAddress){
        try{
            URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
            String sourceCode = "";
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
                if (line.contains("<title>")){
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
                    String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                    temp = temp.replace("<title>","");
                    int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
                    temp = temp.substring(0,lastPos);
                    sourceCode += temp+"\n";
                }
                if (line.contains("<description>")){
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<description>");
                    String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                    temp = temp.replace("<description>","");
                    int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</description>");
                    temp = temp.substring(0,lastPos);
                    sourceCode += temp+"\n";

                }
            }
            in.close();
            return sourceCode;}
            catch(MalformedURLException ue){
                System.out.println("Malformed URL");
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println("Something went wrong reading the comments");
            }
        return urlAddress;


}

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(readRSS("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001"));
    }
}
```

here is my program that I found to help do a frequency of word count

```
package twp.brady.barry;

public class FrequencyOfWords 
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String text = "apples are apples and I love them";
        String[] keys = text.split(" ");
        String[] uniqueKeys;
        int count = 0;

        uniqueKeys = getUniqueKeys(keys);

        for(String key: uniqueKeys)
        {
            if(null == key)
            {
                break;
            }
            for(String s : keys)
            {
                if(key.equals(s))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Count of ["+key+"] is : "+count);
            count=0;
        }
    }
    private static String[] getUniqueKeys(String[] keys)
    {
        String[] uniqueKeys = new String[keys.length];

        uniqueKeys[0] = keys[0];
        int uniqueKeyIndex = 1;
        boolean keyAlreadyExists = false;

        for(int i=1; i<keys.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=uniqueKeyIndex; j++)
            {
                if(keys[i].equals(uniqueKeys[j]))
                {
                    keyAlreadyExists = true;
                }
            }

            if(!keyAlreadyExists)
            {
                uniqueKeys[uniqueKeyIndex] = keys[i];
                uniqueKeyIndex++;
            }
            keyAlreadyExists = false;
        }
        return uniqueKeys;
    }
}
```

I am having trouble finding a way to combine the two so that I can get a word count from the RSS descriptions.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to use the frequency of words program on the RSSreader program, I'm trying to use the frequency of words program to figure out the frequency of words within the description and title of the RSS feeds

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just count the words in the whole RSS feed ? 
Then you just have to replace your line

```
String text = "apples are apples and I love them";
```

by

```
String text = readRSS("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001");
```

If you want to count the appearance of words in each description/title, you have to adjust your readRSS method to not iterate over the whole RSS feed but to stop after each title/description combination and count the words of them.